# Change a section of a window upon click event

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a treeview at the left side of the screen, and when I click on any of the TreeViewItem, I want the right side of the screen to change accordingly.

For example, clicking on 'Project' would display on the right half of the screen, a label for project name along with the project name in a text box, and a similar label-textbox pair for some other fields. Clicking on a sub-option of 'Project' such as 'Task 1' should change the right half of the screen such that instead of labels and textboxes for project name and details, it should now be for task name/details. Atm, I only care about label-textbox pairs but in the future I'll need some more sophisticated options, maybe buttons and tables.

What I thought of was to have a grid premade for each option, when I clicked on 'Project' there would be a grid which displays all the info for a Project. And when I then clicked on 'Task 1', the Project grid should be hidden and the Task grid should be displayed with the fields filled out.

Is this possible? What should I be using to create templates that I can then choose from?

Comment: Are you coding in Code behind or using MVVM

Answer (score 0):

Firoz already mentioned the important bit. A rough guess is that you're not using MVVM pattern, so to minimize the adaption effort, you could add a `Content Control` to your window and set the content of this control whenever a selection is made. You can put any User Control in there.

Using **MVVM** would mean you bind that `Content Control` to a property on your `ViewModel` (of type `UIElement` or `UserControl`) and set an instance whenever a bound selected values changes. Speaking of selected Value, I think the default `TreeView` is not really Binding-friendly, so you might end up with behaviours that do the binding for you.

Comment: Just use `HeirachicalDataTemplate`s and binding to `Treeview`s gets a lot easier.

Comment: Additionally, if you define datatemplates such as `<DataTemplate Type={x:Type MyProject}.../>`, then you don't need to expose a `Control` as your content on your viewmodel. Instead you expose a `MyProject` and WPF converts it to the controls defined inside the `DataTemplate` for you.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking to do is quite easy and possible, but I don't think you are thinking quite big enough.

As your project grows and the number of different things that you want to show expands, then you are going to need to show and hide more and more controls. This is quite quickly going to get unmanageable. Instead think about some other controls deal with this, in some ways you are doing something very like a tabbed dialog, just with a hierarchical set of tabs.

A tabbed dialog has a panel and a set of tabs, when you click on each tab, the content of the panel changes. In fact you can create `UserControl`s one for each specialised set of UI that you want to display, e.g. you could have a `ProjectControl` that displays all of your project textboxes, labels, buttons etc.

In addition WPF has this neat feature called `DataTemplate`s, these define how a type of data should look when it is displayed. So if you where to have a

```
public class MyProject
{
  public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

Then you could define

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type MyProject}>
  <TextBox Text="{Binding Name}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

And WPF will automatically convert the data into to its visual form if you set it as the content of the tab panel.

However this type of displaying content in a panel is not the only WPF control that does this. There is also something called a `NavigationFrame`, which also can be used wrapped into a Window as a `NavigationWindow`. This control provides you ways to navigate to the next `Page` to display. `Page`s can be just like the `UserControl`s in a tabbed dialog, but can also be URIs, enabling you to link in content from the web if you wish. In addition you can call `NavigateTo` from other controls enabling you build much more usable interfaces.

I worked through the process of building a full windows control panel style interface in

- http://alski.net/post/2012/01/11/WPF-Wizards.aspx
- and http://alski.net/post/2012/01/13/WPF-Wizards-part-2-Glass.aspx

I've added later VS2012 style glows in

- http://alski.net/post/2013/09/14/WPF-Re-creating-VS2012Office-2013-window-glow.aspx

And then released the entire source code as open source at

- http://winchrome.codeplex.com/

[image: WinChrome example]

This comes with support for embedding Navigation panels with

```
<WinChrome:SearchableNavigationWindow 
  x:Class="WinChrome.Win7Demo.MainWindow"
...
  xmlns:WinChrome="clr-namespace:WinChrome;assembly=WinChrome" 
  Style="{StaticResource Win7NavigationWindow}">

<WinChrome:SearchableNavigationWindow.Navigation>
    <view:Navigation x:Name="navigationTree"/>
</WinChrome:SearchableNavigationWindow.Navigation>
```

[(Full source code)](http://winchrome.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#WinChrome.Win7Demo/MainWindow.xaml)

Where the navigation window is embedded as, but can also be a TreeView.

```
<UserControl x:Class="WinChrome.View.Navigation"  ...>
  <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" Padding="12,0" 
      VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" >
    <StackPanel>
      <Button 
        Margin="0,12,0,0" Style="{StaticResource LinkNavigatorButtonStyle}" 
        Content="Home" 
       Command="{Binding 
       RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Win7Demo:MainWindow}, AncestorLevel=1}, 
       Path=GoHomeCommand}" />                   
    </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

[(Full source code)](http://winchrome.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#WinChrome.Win7Demo/View/Navigation.xaml)